# formatCreateLabel does not display "Create new label..." for some cases using react-select/creatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select/creatable` library to display dropdowns with options. I wanted to make use of the `formatCreateLabel` prop which displays a label. This label is based on the topmost option in the dropdown, so essentially in the `formatCreateLabel` function, I am sorting my list which is dynamic, and based on the topmost option I am showing the create option. Few things to note here — the create option is dependent on the topmost option in the dropdown list. I also wanted to show the create option even if there is an exact match.

Snippet of the format function:

```js
const formatCreateLabel = (input) => {
  const options = getSortedList(input, list); // using sort-matcher library for sorting
    
  const firstItem = _.first(options);
  const label = _.get(firstItem, 'label');

  if (!_.isNil(firstItem)) return `Create wildcard "${label}"`;
};

/** My list option looks something like this (eg.)
const listOptions = [
  { label: 'alpha', key: 'a', value: 'a' },
  { label: 'alpea', key: 'ae', value: 'ae' },
  { label: 'beta', key: 'b', value: 'b' },
  { label: 'user.name', key: 'user.name', value: 'user.name' },
  { label: 'name', key: 'name', value: 'name' },
];
**/

<CreatableSelect
  key={key}
  options={list}
  value={value}
  onChange={onChange}
  placeholder="Select..."
  formatCreateLabel={formatCreateLabel}
  {...props}
/>
```

The issue is the label is sometimes shown and sometimes it is not although I can see that a valid value is being returned from the `formatCreateLabel` function. What could be the issue here?
Also is there a way to continue showing the create new option even if there is an exact match?